# Safari web inspector not working when debugging ios standalone webapp

Tags: ios, web, safari, homescreen, inspector

I've been struggling to debug my standalone webapp with safari's web inspector. The web inspector works fine when I go to the url on the iphone's safari like a normal web page. The problem appears when I add the webapp to the homescreen. I'm having a strange bug that causes my app to crash when I start it from the homescreen and I want to see what's happening, but when I try to open the web inspector on the mac it opens for a second and then it closes unexpectedly with no message at all (also the webapp on the iphone closes). Thanks in advance. More info about the devices and versions:
- iPhone 5SE with ios 10.3.2 (14F89)
- Macbook Air with MacOS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You will find some info about how to make a great question. Provide us the code you have so far

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem now: @francesco hai trovato soluzione?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that Safari is having a bug regarding the cache when I add the webapp to the homescreen using the same app name I was previously using. I tried deleting the old one on the homescreen and add it again but with a different app name (short name)  and it worked (it loaded the latest version of the webapp) and the bug I was trying to get rid of in the first place was finally gone. I'm concerned however about asking the user to add the app again to the homescreen with a different app name to get the latest version. Maybe that's a sign that I should move on to service workers :)